# Just one chance for a debugger session

Tags: wakanda

In my application, I can debug one time ! I change some lines in a "file".js.You can see what I get on the screen during my first debug session in this first copy screen.

[image]

and the second time....I receive a completely white screen...
I must precise that I don't receive the same comportement if I try the tutorial SuperHero !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this too and it seems to be a bug. Before running the code again, make sure you close the Debugger tab in the left side panel. If that tab is left open after debugging, subsequent debugging produces a blank code area.

Answer (score 1):

close all debugger tabs from the studio (including the one that shows current paused threads) and open the following URL in your browser : http://127.0.0.1:8080/debugger

There is an issue currently being processed about the subject : https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-issues/issues/216